# java garbage collection finalize method not executing

Tags: java, garbage-collection

the following code should print hello world as per the concept of garbage collection in java but doesn't

```
import java.util.*;
public class Final{
  protected void finalize(){
    System.out.println("hello world");
  }
  public static void main(String args[]){
    Final myfinal=new Final();
    myfinal=null;
  }
}
```

Comment: The VM most likely exits before GC and finalizers have a chance to run, since your program doesn't really do anything.

Comment: The GC only runs when it has to and the finalizer only runs after the GC has run.